# Failed to allocate tensors in tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to load a tflite version of a tensorflow implementation of [EAST](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2017/papers/Zhou_EAST_An_Efficient_CVPR_2017_paper.pdf)
text detector with tflite's python interpreter. When I try to allocate the tensors, I get the error:

```
tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/concatenation.cc:75 t->dims->data[d] != t0->dims->data[d] (45 != 46)
Node number 78 (CONCATENATION) failed to prepare.

Failed to allocate tensors!
```

I have fixed the size of the model during conversion and I get the error even when keeping the size choosen. Here is a sample of the code that fails:

```py
from tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter import Interpreter

model = Interpreter(model_path='frozen_east_text_detection.tflite')
model.allocate_tensors()
```

Even though I found similar issues on tensorflow's [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues), I can't find any solution, does anyone have a solution? Or at least know what is the cause of the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing the model building code. The error states clearly that a concatenation is requested but the operands have different sizes in one of the dimensions. Only the concatenation axis can have different sizes between the operands.

Comment: I think it's a conversion of this one but I don't have any more information.
https://www.kaggle.com/yelmurat/frozen-east-text-detection